# mySql Which is method is faster

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have 2 tables for a contacts book application

first one (called members) includes Full Name and Unique ID
second one (called phones) includes ID (phone ID) and memberID (to which member this phone belongs) and phone number.

To display the member's phone numbers.

Should I add a new field to the table members to store an array of phones IDs and update it every time a member add or delete a phone to his contacts book? 
to print the contacts book, i will get the array and make a query to the phones table!

or

not store the ids in the members table. and just make a query where memberID=XX

which one is better and faster?

Comment: The second option seems far more logical. Easier to query and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option is much simpler to program and troubleshoot.  Use it.

Your first option is called "denormalization" in DBMS jargon.  Sometimes it makes sense to denormalize a database with very large tables, to speed it up.  But mySQL is a good relational database, and works well with normalized tables as you describe.

When your application grows and you have, say, more than one hundred million rows in your telephone-number table, you may find that denormalization makes sense.  For now, it doesn't.